# Does the FSCS protection limit of £85K mean I have to spread my pension pot across different providers?

Tags: united-kingdom, pension-sipp, fscs

Considering the [FSCS](https://www.fscs.org.uk/what-we-cover/pensions/) only pays compensation up to £85k in the event of a SIPP provider going bust, should I be spreading my pensions across different providers even if I predominantly invest in stock and shares, and not cash?

I understand as the money is invested in funds, the provider going bust should mean the underlying funds are safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't checked all of them, but I'm pretty sure all UK SIPP providers will hold (uninvested) client money in trust, or at least in segregated accounts. Here are some examples:

[Hargreaves Lansdown](https://www.hl.co.uk/security-centre/how-safe-is-your-investment)

> All client money is held by us on trust and is segregated from our own
> funds in accordance with the FCA’s client money rules and guidance so
> that any creditors of Hargreaves Lansdown would have no legal right to
> it and we cannot use any of this money to cover Hargreaves Lansdown's
> obligations.

[Interactive Investor](https://www.ii.co.uk/about-ii/your-protection)

> Any money (cash) held in your account is treated as ‘client money’ as
> defined by the FCA. This means your money also has trust status, and
> is deposited across a range of bank accounts specially designated as
> holding client money. At no point does your cash enter an ii bank
> account.

[Fidelity](https://www.fidelity.co.uk/how-is-my-money-protected/)

(interestingly doesn't use the phrase "in trust")

> Investment firms such as Fidelity are very different from banks
> because we are required to separate client money and assets from our
> own resources. We are not permitted to use client money and assets in
> the course of our own business activities, and your money would be
> ring-fenced in the unlikely event that we became insolvent.

In general a site-specific search for the term fscs will get you to a provider's 'reassurance' page(s).

Comment: So Vanguard is not great? https://www.vanguardinvestor.co.uk/need-help/answer/are-investments-covered-by-the-fscs

Comment: @Dan 10 para 2 https://www.vanguardinvestor.co.uk/articles/latest-thoughts/how-it-works/your-10-most-common-questions and https://www.vanguardinvestor.co.uk/need-help/answer/what-happens-to-my-money-if-vanguard-becomes-insolvent seem pretty clear. I think most people don't have that much *cash as cash* in a SIPP so it never really comes up